# How to create a rollup field on a related entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Perhaps I'm overcomplicating how this is represented in Dynamics 365 because on paper it seems simple to me. I have the image representation of the setup below:

[image]

I want to create a rollup field on Entity C that counts all records of Entity A that have the same Shared ID as a record in Entity C. I would then like to filter that result down based on field values on Entity A. I have tried creating a 1:N relationship from Entity C to Entity A, but I'm not sure how I can specify that Shared ID is the common field between the two entities. How can I go about creating such a relationship and then filtering the data down further?

Comment: Unfortunately you can only add a relationship to a depth of 1 level (e.g. C -> B) so it's not possible to do C -> B -> A

Comment: You can't add 1:N on Entity C to Entity A and then map the shared field ID in that relationship? I tried doing that but when I create the field it shows the related entity, but when I add filters all the fields only have options for Contains Data/Does Not Contain Data. I see the fields fill out on the filter for Entity A but, for example, for fields which are option sets I'm only able to check for the presence of data rather than filtering on what their value might equal